# Need to add <!-- before a tag in an xml file using shell

Tags: unix

My input file is below

INPUT FILE

```
<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>
<Code>777</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Saurav</entryName>
<Code>666</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Ankur</entryName>
<Code>555</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>
```

I have code which looks like

```
LineNum=`grep -n "Deep" deep.xml | cut -d: -f 1 | awk -F '[\t]' '{$NF = $NF -1;}1'`
sed -i "/$LineNum/s/^/<!--/" deep.xml
```

What i need is:- i want to go to the line number which i am getting with LineNum variable and i want to add <!-- before an xml tag. So that my sample output looks like below

```
<!--<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Deep</entryName>
<Code>777</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Saurav</entryName>
<Code>666</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>


<ReconSummary>
<entryName>Total Ankur</entryName>
<Code>555</Code>
<License>L</License>
<Tran>H20</Tran>
<job>1234</job>
</ReconSummary>
```

I am not able to do that. Can anyone tell what mistake i am doing in the code?

Comment: Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: cross-posted on U&L https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/460009/deep-mukherjee?tab=questions